# How to solve this aggregate production problem?

Tags: aggregate-production

Consider a continuum of firms indexed by $a\in [0,1]$ and that $a$ is uniformaly distributed. a firm of type $a$ has a production set $Y^n$ as depicted in the figure below. note that good 1 is used as an input to produce good 2. suppose that the price of the input (good 1) is fixed at $w=1$ while the price of output is $p>0$.

How should I get the input demand and output supply of a firm of type $a$ when the price of output is $p$? And what is the aggregate or average input demand and output supply when the output price is $p$? And what is the aggregate (or average) production set?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let's first look at the profit of a single firm with parameter $a$. Let us denote by $x = -y_1$ the input and $f(x) = y_2$ the output.

The production function is the following:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } x < a,\\ x - a &\text{ if } a \le x \le 1+a,\\ 1 &\text{ if } x > 1+a\end{cases}
$$

The firm optimizes profits:
$$
x^\ast = \arg\max_x p f(x) - x.
$$

You can solve this by looking at various scenarios and taking the best (profit maximising) one.

1. if $x^\ast < a$ then profits are $p 0 - x^\ast$, so here it is best to put $x^\ast = 0$.
2. if $a \le x^\ast \le 1+a$ then profits are $p(x^\ast - a) - x^\ast= (p-1)x^\ast - pa$. If $p > 1$ then profits increase in $x^\ast$ so it is best to put $x^\ast = 1+a$ and profits will be $p - 1 - a$. if $p < 1$, then it is best to set $x^\ast = a$ and profits will be $-a$ (which is negative). In the latter case, it will be best to produce nothing.
3. if $x^\ast \ge 1+a$ then profits are $p - x^\ast$ so here it is optimal to put $x = 1+a$ and profits are given by $p - 1 - a$.

As such, we see that profits are either equal to $p-1-a$ with optimal demand $x^\ast = 1+a$ or equal to zero with optimal demand $x^\ast = 0$.

The first will be optimal if $a \le p-1$, while the second is optimal if $a > p-1$. This gives the following optimal demand for a firm with parameter $a$:
$$
x^\ast = \begin{cases} 1+a &\text{ if } a\le p-1 \\ 0 &\text{ if } a > p-1\end{cases}
$$

Now let us derive optimal aggregate demand. If $p < 1$ then $a \ge 0 > p-1$ so no firm will demand anything: aggregate demand equals zero.

If $p > 2$ then $a \le 1 \le p - 1$ so the firm of type $a$ will demand $1+a$. Aggregate demand is then given by:
$$
\int_0^1 (1+a) da = [a + a^2/2]^1_0 = \frac{3}{2}.
$$

If $1 \le p \le 2$ then firms with $a \le p-1$ will demand $1+a$ and firms with $a > p-1$ will not demand anything. As such, aggreagate demand is:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{p-1} (1+a) da &= [a + a^2/2]^{(p-1)}_0 \\
&= (p-1) + \frac{(p-1)^2}{2} \\
&= p-1 + \frac{p^2}{2} - \frac{2p}{2} + \frac{1}{2},\\
& = \frac{p^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
$$

We get
$$
\text{aggregate demand} = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } p < 1\\ \frac{p^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2} &\text{ if } 1 \le p \le 2\\ 
\frac{3}{2} &\text{ if } p > 2.\end{cases}
$$

Aggregate demand is given below.
[image: aggregate supply]

Comment: According to the "production function" (<<a production set Yn as depicted in the figure below>>), the firm cannot produce more than 1 unit of output.

Comment: @escaiguolquer thanks. I made some corrections (supply->demand)

Comment: Hi - What is the average production set in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Observing the highest possible iso-profit curve passing through the feasible set, we obtain the supply of $y_2$ and demand for $y_1$ as follows. Here iso-profit curve is set of $(y_1,y_2)$ pairs that yields the same level of profit given $p$.

[image]

So,
\begin{eqnarray*} (y_1^d,y_2^s)(p)\in\begin{cases}\{(0,0),(1+a,1)\} & \text{if } p = 1+a \\ \{(1+a,1)\} & \text{if } p > 1+a \\ \{(0,0)\} & \text{if } p < 1+a \end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

Corresponding optimal profit is

\begin{eqnarray*} \pi(p)=\max(0,p-(1+a)) \end{eqnarray*}

Given that $a\sim\text{Unif}(0,1)$, aggregate input demand is
\begin{eqnarray*}Y_1^d(p) = \int_0^1y_1^d(p)da = \begin{cases} \int_0^{1}(1+a)da=\frac{3}{2} & \text{if } p \geq 2 \\ 0 & \text{if } p \leq 1 \\ \int_0^{p-1}(1+a)da=\dfrac{(p-1)(p+1)}{2} & \text{if } 1 < p < 2\end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

Aggregate output supply is
\begin{eqnarray*}Y_2^s(p) = \int_0^1y_2^s(p)da = \begin{cases} \int_0^{1}da=1 & \text{if } p \geq 2 \\ 0 & \text{if } p \leq 1 \\ \int_0^{p-1}da=p-1 & \text{if } 1 < p < 2\end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Hi - What is the average production set in this case?

Comment: Boundary of the aggregate Production Set is given by $g(y_1)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{for } y_1<-2\\ \int_0^1 \min(-y_1-a,1)da & \text{for } -2\leq y_1\leq -1 \\ \int_0^1 \max(-y_1-a,0)da & \text{for } -1<y_1\leq 0 \end{cases}$ and aggregate production set is simply $\{(y_1,y_2)|0\leq y_2\leq g(y_1)\}$